# What are some common questions regarding the theorem of Pappus?

Tags: integration

Today, our physics tutor hinted that the theorem of Pappus would be tested in the following exam.

Now I know that I can determine the volume of a sphere by rotating a semicircle of radius a around the y-axis.

Are there some other common cases about the theorem that is usually tested?

Comment: I'll bet a chocolate fish that the test question is a donut.

Comment: A typical example used when teaching the theorem of Pappus is finding the volume of a torus.